# Why does a div spill out of the parent wrapper in HTML

Tags: css, html

I don't seem to position a div as I want it be. The basic structure of my HTML is

```
    Header
    main{
         nav// top strip
         #leftContain  //left half-bar
         #rigthContain //right half-bar:**this one spills out**
         }
    footer
```

Here is the HTML minus the CSS link(not relavent as the relevant ones I have kept inline here)and minus the HTML tag/metatag/head tag/javascript tags)Also the images references doesn't make any difference so I ignored those too

```
 <body>
    <header style="width:1020px;margin:0 auto">
        <h1>Company logo</h1>
     </header>
    <main id="wrapper" style="width:1020px;margin:0 auto">


     <nav style="  line-height:30px; background-color:#ff0000;height:30px;width:100%;">
     <p style="font-family: '21st Century', fantasy">
     <a href="">products + Solutions</a> 
     <a href="">Services</a>
     <a href="">industries</a>
     <a href="">resources</a>
     <a href="">company</a>
     <a href="">investors</a>
     <a href="">Careers</a>
     </p>
     </nav>

         <div id="leftContain" style="width:500px">
             <section id="headContent">
             <p style="color:red;font-size:44px;margin-top:17px;margin-bottom:10px;line-height: 110%;">See how our engineer perfectly matched their DNA
             </p>
             <p style="margin-top:2px;line-height: 120%;">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. 
             </p>
             </section>
             <hr>

             <section class="picTile" style="width:550px;height:170px;overflow:hidden">
                <img src="assets/images/item1.jpg" style="width:250px;float:left">
                <div style="width:250px;float:left">
                    <p style="margin-top:0;margin-left:4px;line-height: 90%;line-height: 120%;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.
                    </p>
                </div>
             </section>
             <hr>

             <section class="picTile" style="width:550px;height:170px;overflow:hidden">
                <img src="assets/images/item2.jpg" style="width:250px;float:left">
                <div style="width:250px;float:left">
                    <p style="margin-top:0;margin-left:4px;line-height: 120%;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.
                    </p>
                </div>
             </section>
             <hr>


             <section class="picTile" style="width:550px;height:170px;margin-bottom:10px;overflow:hidden">
                <img src="assets/images/item3.jpg" style="width:250px;float:left">
                <div style="width:250px;float:left">
                    <p style="margin-top:0;margin-left:4px;line-height: 120%;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec.
                    </p>
                </div>  
             </section>
            <hr>
         </div>

         <div id="RightContain" style="width:500px;float:left" >
            <section id="banner;" style="float:left;width:200px">
            #banner
                <img src="assets/images/dr_left_slideshow.svg">
            </section>
            <section id="contactForm">
            </section>
         </div>



    </main>
    <footer style=" position:relative;bottom:0;width:100%;height:60px;">
     <p>Privacy policy +terms of use | C 2014</p>
    </footer>


  </body>
```

I want the #rightContain and #leftContain div to be besides each other,but it doesn't happen so ,the #rightContain slips out of the wrapping main div and goes to the bottom of the screen

Comment: It might be useful to provide a working code snippet or [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/), so we can see the issue in action

Comment: I never tried fiddle, I went to their website and ran my script but didn't find a way to share my result, :(

Comment: In the top-bar on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/), you can just save your fiddle, and then paste the link from the address bar into your question here at StackOverflow.

Comment: got it ,thanks,would skip that for this question as I've already got the answer ,but this would be helpful henceforth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this but I think the one you're looking for would be to wrap both right and left contain in a `div` with this css:

```
{display:table;width:100%;table-layout:fixed;}
```

then add the following css to both right and left contain:

```
{display:table-cell;vertical-align:top;width:100%;}
```

This will give equal width to both div and keep them the same height and also sit them side by side regardless of page width.

Comment: It does work , but I still want  to know why the code I had written didn't gave me the required results

Comment: Its because a div is a block element that will basically make it go full width and push anything else underneath it. so in order to tell them to sit side beside you'd want to inline it or more effectivly inline-block it but that will still cause the undesired drop in content that you have so the best thing is to tell the divs to act like dhildren cell's of a table so that they behave like a table row where each div is considered a cell and should sit inline of each other and should share similar width and heights.

Comment: Oh I see ,I was under the impression stating float overwrites that condition

Comment: Not exactly you would need to give them slightly more equal widths and deduct things like margins and padding from your containers and your divs.

I avoid float at all costs for one main reason it doesnt like to respect content around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float: left;` to the style of leftContain.